# Traceless matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is a traceless real matrix similar to any nice matrix?

I am trying to understand the actual meaning of harmonic functions (those functions $u$ for which the divergence of the gradient of $u$ is zero).

Comment: Please define "nice matrix" ...

Comment: Some matrix which is easy to deal with - like upper triangular, zero diagonal etc.

Comment: Well, then yes: a traceless matrix is similar (even unitarily) to a matrix with all its diagonal entries equal to zero...at least in characteristic zero. In positive characteristic I'm not quite sure, though the unitary thing goes down, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Any matrix is similar to its Jordan form, which is upper triangular. From this points of view, the only information that you get from the matrix being traceless is that the sum of the eigenvalues is zero.

From another point of view, it is well known that any trace-zero matrix is a commutator, i.e. it is of the form $XY-YX$.